# Changing an html website to Wordpress and missing the Parent Theme

Tags: parent-theme

I have been trying to change my HTML website over to Wordpress. When I load the new theme, it says it is installed but that the Parent Theme is missing, please install. How do I do that? I have copy and pasted all the code into the files to transfer it to Wordpress. These files are header.php, footer.php, style.css, and sidebar.php. This website was designed years ago and was HTML. I feel like I am really close but I don't know how to create the Parent Theme when it was created outside of Wordpress. Please help if you can.
Best,
Helen

Answer (score 0):

You miss `index.php` as it is required - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/what-is-a-theme/#required-files

In `style.css` you have setup your theme as a child, that is second option for this message.

Parent theme is two file `style.css` and `index.php`. This parent theme style need to be without line about template - remove 7 line from this example if you have - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#2-create-a-stylesheet-style-css
Template line suggest using it as child theme rather than parent

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I forgot to mention that I do have index.php as well.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention that I do have index.php as well. I just removed line seven in the style.css file.

Comment: in my index.php file, I have the following code:'

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
 <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: i followed the following steps in this article:

Comment: https://www.highervisibility.com/blog/converting-html-to-wordpress-step-by-step-tutorial/

Comment: Do you remove any other themes? Twenty Twenty is default one and not to be removed in any time. Can you provide some screenshoot from this page `/wp-admin/themes.php`
Is there showing anything on homepage? Pleas add some static text to test if working. 
Steps in provided article are for creating child theme. Your goal is to create child theme or parent one? Maybe it's working or other error occur right now

Comment: I did not remove any themes.

Comment: I can't seem to drop the screenshot in this comment box.

Comment: Should I put Twenty Twenty as the Template on the style sheet css?

Comment: Pleas edit question and attach images. You add url that is local for your computer and is dangerous to share in internet. Pleas remove it :)

Comment: how do I add an image? I had my website as an html site for years and would upload via Filezilla. So, I took the files from my website that were HTML and tried to copy and paste the code into new Wordpress files. Wordpress says there is no Parent Theme. And that my site is Child. So, what file am I missing for the Parent Theme when transferring it from an HTML site?

Comment: I have style.css and index.php that I have built for the Wordpress version of my site. But it is still saying there is no Parent Theme

Comment: Pleas copy and paste style.css to your question - otherwise I cannot help you nor somebody else ;/